# Multiple Selection with UITableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am fairly new to iOS development, especially to using Swift. I want to implement a list where the user can select different checkmarks on different rows and then submit the choices for processing.

Apple has a code sample but it is done in Objective-C and I am looking for something similar in Swift. Any support would be appreciated

Apple Objective-C Example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html

Thanks

Comment: Have a go at translating it yourself. Objective-C syntax is a little odd, but the method names are similar and autocorrect will give you suggestions to help you along. Show us the parts you are having trouble with along with what you've done and we'll help you along. Stack Overflow won't translate your whole project, but does reward effort.

Comment: @vacawama I didn't request a translation of the code to swift, I barely sought any knowledge of something similar to this in swift. The stackoverflow platform is primarily there for exchanging experience, and as a coder I thought best to ask if something exist already out there before attempting to do it myself from scratch. Thanks for your support.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that you just were asking for a translation. I believe that it is worth your effort to learn enough Objective-C that you can read it. It's really only a small layer atop C. Once you do that, you can see what Apple is doing in their example and then gain the knowledge of how that kind of thing is written.

Comment: Thanks @vacawama am sure you meant well. Will look at it and give it a try. If I get stuck, I will let you know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code for multiple selection and for checkmark

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

        if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){

            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;

        }else{

            cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;

        }
    }
```